# Missing Mappings in SSIS Project

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I got a working Integration Services project (`*.dtproj`). The task was to add several columns.
I edited my tables in the database accordingly. In the SSIS project I edited some SQL queries and added some mappings.

Example of some mappings in SSIS:

[image: example]

After running the project, it also worked as expected: The new columns in the tables were added with content.

But after exporting the project onto another machine (copy-paste the SSIS project folder and the entire SQL script), the mappings of the **newly created columns** are missing. All other (old) mappings are still there.

Example of a missing (ignored) mapping:

[image]

Is there any way to export the SSIS project to another machine with all my mappings?

Comment: have you found the solution and the root cause yet?